# Formatting Numbers as Text Using VBA and Fixed Method

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of numbers that need to be converted to text, with 2 decimal places.  Excel has the FIXED function that does this directly within Excel.  However, when I try to do it within VBA, it doesn't work.  I don't get an error, but the numbers are not formatted correctly. Here is the macro that I have so far:

```
Sub FormatNumAsText()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NumComponents As Long
    Dim RangeProp As Range
    Dim strFixed As String
    
    Set RangeProp = Range(Range("C1"), Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    NumComponents = RangeProp.Rows.Count
        
    For i = 2 To NumComponents
        strFixed = WorksheetFunction.Fixed(Cells(i, 3), 2, True)
        Cells(i, 3).Value = strFixed
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting: `Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "@"` just before `Cells(i, 3).Value = strFixed`

Comment: [link] (https://imgur.com/D6dhZfx)

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner.  That did the trick.